# When I run the code, I get an error the guesses is not defined

Tags: python

I made this quiz game. It runs fine, and you can answer, but when you press answer, it gives me an error. I've tried switching variables, but I don't know where it started. Here's my code.

```
def new_game():
    geusses = []
    correct_geusses = 0
    question_num = 1
    
    for key in questions:
        print(key)
        for i in options [question_num-1]:
            print(i)
            guess = input("Enter(A, B, C, or D)")
            guess = guess.upper()
            guesses.append(guesses)
            
            correct_geusses += check_answer(questions.get(key),guess)
            question_num += 1
#-----------------------
def check_answer(answer, guess):
    
    if answer == guesses:
        print("Nice Job!")
        return 1 
    else:
        print("Wrong!")
#-----------------------
def display_score():
    pass
#-----------------------
def play_again():
    pass
#-----------------------

questions = {
    "Who was the first US president? : " : "A"
}
#----------------------------

options = [["A. George Washington," "B. Ben Franklin," "C. Elon Musk," "D. None of the above" ]]
#-----------------------------------

new_game()
```

Comment: Please add the error to the question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The next code should fix mistakes:

```
def new_game():
    guesses = []
    correct_guesses = 0
    question_num = 1
    
    for key in questions:
        print(key)
        for i in options [question_num-1]:
            print(i)
            guess = input("Enter(A, B, C, or D) - ")
            guess = guess.upper()
            guesses.append(guesses)
            
            correct_guesses += check_answer(questions.get(key), guess)
            question_num += 1

def check_answer(answer, guess):
    if answer == guess:
        print("Nice Job!")
        return 1 
    else:
        print("Wrong!")
        return 0

def display_score():
    pass

def play_again():
    pass


questions = {
    "Who was the first US president? : " : "A"
}

options = [["A. George Washington," "B. Ben Franklin," "C. Elon Musk," "D. None of the above" ]]

new_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Your list is named `geusses` and than you try to add elements to list named `guesses`.